# Add a dependency with abstraction

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a web api project which has many layers.
We have created another application in which we want to add a refence to one of the layers of the 1st application, this reference is a project helper for EF lamda expression (we passe some criteria and we return an IQueryable) this project has many other dependencies, we want create a project wrapper in which we add all references so we don't need to add each refence in all layers of the 2 n application
Each application has its owne context.
How could we achieve this ?

Comment: Maybe you should create a separate project/dll containing all those EF helpers. Decoupling those utilities from the rest of the application will result in a less layer as well and will make your code reusable.